# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation of a CALayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, cgaffinetransform

I create a layer and I set a frame for it.
Then I apply a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to it. The result of this is a squeezed object because the frame remains the same. How do I rotate the layer and also reset the frame so it would not look squeezed.

Comment: Doesnt CALayer have a CATransform3D? If that is your problem, you can change your affine transform to 3D with CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform().

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're trying and what you'd like to achieve?  I don't really understand your question right now, because rotating an object does nothing to its size, so its bounds remain the same.  Nothing gets squeezed with a simple 2-D rotation.

Comment: I understood that setting the frame after performing a transform (in this case rotation) is somehow behind this unexpected behavior. In my case I reset the frame and transform repeatedly because my layer is changing its position constantly. But still, I couldn't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it: instead of setting the frame, I set the center (position) and bounds. This way, miraculously the problem disappears.